# US Embassy ds 160 form for B1 visa in london

Tags: visas, usa, london, business-travel

I applied for a B1 visa and attended the visa interview at the London site on 02/07/2019. It was approved by the officer and he said I should receive it in a few working days. However, the photo I uploaded to the DS160 form is a few years old (same as my UK passport) which I have just realized is not suitable but the hard copy photo that I supplied them was taken a few days ago which is. The visa officers did not raise this issue at the interview so I would just like to inform them about this. Hence, I have emailed them but will this make any difference? I also submitted the updated photo along with the application that is 2x2inches so do you think they will realise this and use the new photo or do I need to do something?

Comment: In which way is the photo "not suitable", if it is good enough for your passport?

Comment: it was taken more than 6 months ago (3 years ago). I mean, I look very similar but it's the photo I used for my British passport issued 3 years ago and so it's pretty obvious that it doesn't conform to the guidelines in the strictest sense.

Comment: If you gave them a hard copy photo at the interview, then they ought to use that, I would think.